# senenium unable to get browser when try switch to Certificate error window

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, certificate

I faced with problem of Certificate error in IE9 while using selenium webdriver.
I use such code:

```
driver.get(url);
driver.navigate().to("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()");
```

but get exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 14 milliseconds
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the certificate error either a) doesn't appear all the time, or b) isn't present when your navigate command is issue.

Try a) surrounding in a try/catch block to dismiss the NoSuchWindowException when the certificate error doesn't appear, or b) waiting for the page to load/the certificate error to be present